# upload zip folder onto remote server using PHP?

Tags: php, curl

i am trying to upload a zip folder onto a remote server using PHP CURL but i have no idea why the zip folder/file that is uploaded onto the remote server is empty!

basically the file gets uploaded (some how) but when i look at the uploaded folder, it shows as `0 bytes` but the zip folder has `700 bytes` of files in it!

here is my code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="myfile.php">
  <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" value="choose">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>



<?php
if (isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']) ) {
    $filePath  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];

    $POST_DATA = array(
        'file' => '@'.  realpath($filePath)
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://remotesite/handle.php');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);

     if($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
        $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
        echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
    } else {
        echo "<h2>File Uploaded</h2>";
    }
}
?>
```

and this is my handle.php code:

```
<?php
$encoded_file = $_POST['file'];
$decoded_file = base64_decode($encoded_file);
/* Now you can copy the uploaded file to your server. */
file_put_contents('subins.zip', $decoded_file);
?>
```

could someone please let me know what I am missing or doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does it work with other filetypes? Check to make sure the server isn't running into a disk quota problem.

Comment: You're looking at $POST['file'] in handle.php but the input appears to be called uploadefile. Regardless, you put the contents into the zip file but never attempt to 'unzip' it into a folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a file with a post to php it creat a temporary copied files who gonna disappears when the script ends. You need to store the uploaded file into a different location:

Handle.php :

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
      // Move the file to the desired directory
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  }
```

Comment: is there anyway, to move the uploaded file to the root folder instead of keeping it in upload folder? for example moving it to public_html folder? I did try the rename(); and I also tried `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);` bellow all the other codes but it doesn't move the uploaded folder to the public_html. any suggestion?

Comment: @shell Either you put the full path /home/user/public_html for example or more  in a more flexible way `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  realpath('../').'/'. $_FILES["file"]["name"];`

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't move the file to the public_html! it does upload it to the upload folder but doesn't copy or move it to the public_html!

Comment: @shell Try `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], '/home/user/public_html '. $_FILES["file"]["name"]); // Adjust to your full desired path`

Comment: still doesn't move it to the public)html. I made sure the path is correct as well... is there anyway, to move anything and everything that is in upload folder to the public_html?

Comment: I've managed to do it using rename(); function in the end. thanks